# clearInterval and pausing a game

Tags: javascript, html

```
  this.update = function() {
    if (state == "game") {
      if (jaws.pressed("p") && !jaws.paused) {
        jaws.paused = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
          var unpause_interval_id = setInterval(function() {
            if (jaws.pressed("p") && jaws.paused) {
              jaws.paused = false;
              clearInterval(unpause_interval_id);
            }
          });
        }, 5000);
      }
```

That is my attempt at pausing a game I'm working on. Basically, when the player pauses, I set a timeout of 5 seconds to a function that checks if the player wants to unpause.

However, I am not being successful at clearing the interval, the clearInterval function isn't work, I'm sure of it from what I've debugged. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to clear interval without if (jaws.pressed("p") && jaws.paused)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
function p_unp()
{
   jaws.paused = !jaws.paused;
}

jaws.on_keypress("p", p_unp);
```

Comment: That works, but how can I make it so that the player has to wait X seconds before he can unpause again? Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend to remove `setInterval` function. The `while loop` instead:

```
  this.update = function() {
    if (state == "game") {
      if (jaws.pressed("p") && !jaws.paused) {
        jaws.paused = true;
        while (jaws.paused) {
            if (jaws.pressed("p") && jaws.paused) {
              jaws.paused = false;
            }
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Seems no good. Browser can detect such script us bugged and ask user for termination. Also this can cause overload